# How to visualize screen overlaps in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

Is there some way to show the overlapping between two screens in chrome? I usually use "page up" and "page down" when I read on my computer. This works quite well in Acrobat Reader as it detects the last line of the previous screen (or page) and only shows the new content. The worst case is: I have one additional line of old text.

In Chrome a significant part of both screens overlap (usually 5-7 lines). It is very bothersome to find the point where I stopped reading, especially if this is the last portion of the website and the screen shows way more than 5-7 lines of the old text.

I want to have a visual mark where the old stuff stops and the new content begins. Something like this mockup:

Imagine I read this page and I am done reading. I press "scroll down".

[image]

As you can see about 5 lines overlap. I want something like the grey line that shows me where to pick up reading.

[image]

Does such an addon or plugin exist for chrome? I do not care how the visualization is provided. The old text might be hi-lighted or grey.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

MagicScroll. Kinda.

[Demo](http://www.magicscroll.net/ScrollTheWeb.html), [Chrome Addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magicscroll-web-reader/ecldhagehndokdmaiaigoaecbmbnmfkc), [Source](https://github.com/rdwallis/MagicScrollWebReader), [HN Discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5043388) (which also mentions [Beeline Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beeline-reader/lcacgebkomahcbghabmikokgjkflmlko))